# Why does the MPI program terminate with exit code 134 (signal 6)?

Tags: c, mpi, exit-code, mpich

I have the following huffman compression code written with MPI.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include "../include/serialHeader.h"

struct huffmanDictionary huffmanDictionary[256];
struct huffmanTree *head_huffmanTreeNode = NULL;
struct huffmanTree huffmanTreeNode[512];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    clock_t start, end;
    unsigned int cpu_time_used;
    unsigned int i, j, rank, numProcesses, blockLength;
    unsigned int *compBlockLengthArray;
    unsigned int distinctCharacterCount, combinedHuffmanNodes, frequency[256], inputFileLength, compBlockLength;
    unsigned char *inputFileData, *compressedData, writeBit = 0, bitsFilled = 0, bitSequence[255], bitSequenceLength = 0;
    FILE *inputFile;

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv);
    MPI_File mpi_inputFile, mpi_compressedFile;
    MPI_Status status;

    // get rank and number of processes value
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcesses);

    // get file size
    if(rank == 0){
        inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        inputFileLength = ftell(inputFile);
        fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fclose(inputFile);
    }

    //broadcast size of file to all the processes 
    MPI_Bcast(&inputFileLength, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // get file chunk size

    blockLength = inputFileLength / numProcesses;
    printf ("%u\n", numProcesses);

    if(rank == (numProcesses-1)){
        blockLength = inputFileLength - ((numProcesses-1) * blockLength);   
    }

    // open file in each process and read data and allocate memory for compressed data
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &mpi_inputFile);
    MPI_File_seek(mpi_inputFile, rank * blockLength, MPI_SEEK_SET);

    inputFileData = (unsigned char *)malloc(blockLength * sizeof(unsigned char));   
    MPI_File_read(mpi_inputFile, inputFileData, blockLength, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, &status);

    for (i=0; i< blockLength; ++i)
        printf ("%c\n", inputFileData[i]);
    // start clock
    if(rank == 0){
        start = clock();
    }

    // find the frequency of each symbols
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        frequency[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < blockLength; i++){
        frequency[inputFileData[i]]++;
    }

    compressedData = (unsigned char *)malloc(blockLength * sizeof(unsigned char));  
    compBlockLengthArray = (unsigned int *)malloc(numProcesses * sizeof(unsigned int));

    // initialize nodes of huffman tree
    distinctCharacterCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        if (frequency[i] > 0){
            huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount].count = frequency[i];
            huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount].letter = i;
            huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount].left = NULL;
            huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount].right = NULL;
            distinctCharacterCount++;
        }
    }

    // build tree 
    for (i = 0; i < distinctCharacterCount - 1; i++){
        combinedHuffmanNodes = 2 * i;
        sortHuffmanTree(i, distinctCharacterCount, combinedHuffmanNodes);
        buildHuffmanTree(i, distinctCharacterCount, combinedHuffmanNodes);
    }

    if(distinctCharacterCount == 1){
      head_huffmanTreeNode = &huffmanTreeNode[0];
    }

    // build table having the bitSequence sequence and its length
    buildHuffmanDictionary(head_huffmanTreeNode, bitSequence, bitSequenceLength);

    // compress
    compBlockLength = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < blockLength; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < huffmanDictionary[inputFileData[i]].bitSequenceLength; j++){
            if (huffmanDictionary[inputFileData[i]].bitSequence[j] == 0){
                writeBit = writeBit << 1;
                bitsFilled++;
            }
            else{
                writeBit = (writeBit << 1) | 01;
                bitsFilled++;
            }
            if (bitsFilled == 8){
                compressedData[compBlockLength] = writeBit;
                bitsFilled = 0;
                writeBit = 0;
                compBlockLength++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (bitsFilled != 0){
        for (i = 0; (unsigned char)i < 8 - bitsFilled; i++){
            writeBit = writeBit << 1;
        }
        compressedData[compBlockLength] = writeBit;
        compBlockLength++;
    }

    // calculate length of compressed data
    compBlockLength = compBlockLength + 1024;
    compBlockLengthArray[rank] = compBlockLength;

    // send the length of each process to process 0
    MPI_Gather(&compBlockLength, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, compBlockLengthArray, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // update the data to reflect the offset
    if(rank == 0){
        compBlockLengthArray[0] = (numProcesses + 2) * 4 + compBlockLengthArray[0];
        for(i = 1; i < numProcesses; i++){
            compBlockLengthArray[i] = compBlockLengthArray[i] + compBlockLengthArray[i - 1];
        }
        for(i = (numProcesses - 1); i > 0; i--){
            compBlockLengthArray[i] = compBlockLengthArray[i - 1];
        }
        compBlockLengthArray[0] = (numProcesses + 2) * 4;
    }

    // broadcast size of each compressed data block to all the processes 
    MPI_Bcast(compBlockLengthArray, numProcesses, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // get time
    if(rank == 0){
        end = clock();
        cpu_time_used = ((end - start)) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Time taken: %d:%d s\n", cpu_time_used / 1000, cpu_time_used % 1000);
    }

    // write data to file
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[2], MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &mpi_compressedFile);

    if(rank == 0){
        MPI_File_write(mpi_compressedFile, &inputFileLength, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_File_write(mpi_compressedFile, &numProcesses, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_File_write(mpi_compressedFile, compBlockLengthArray, numProcesses, MPI_UNSIGNED, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    MPI_File_seek(mpi_compressedFile, compBlockLengthArray[rank], MPI_SEEK_SET);
    MPI_File_write(mpi_compressedFile, frequency, 256, MPI_UNSIGNED, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_File_write(mpi_compressedFile, compressedData, (compBlockLength - 1024), MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    // close open files
    MPI_File_close(&mpi_compressedFile);    
    MPI_File_close(&mpi_inputFile);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0)
    free(head_huffmanTreeNode);
    free(compBlockLengthArray);
    free(inputFileData);
    free(compressedData);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code with files:

`mpicc MPICompress.c ../include/serialFunctions.c -o ../bin/MPI_compress`

File (serialFunctions.c):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "serialHeader.h"

// sort nodes based on frequency
void sortHuffmanTree(int i, int distinctCharacterCount, int mergedHuffmanNodes){
    int a, b;
    for (a = mergedHuffmanNodes; a < distinctCharacterCount - 1 + i; a++){
        for (b = mergedHuffmanNodes; b < distinctCharacterCount - 1 + i; b++){
            if (huffmanTreeNode[b].count > huffmanTreeNode[b + 1].count){
                struct huffmanTree temp_huffmanTreeNode = huffmanTreeNode[b];
                huffmanTreeNode[b] = huffmanTreeNode[b + 1];
                huffmanTreeNode[b + 1] = temp_huffmanTreeNode;
            }
        }
    }
}

// build tree based on sort result
void buildHuffmanTree(int i, int distinctCharacterCount, int mergedHuffmanNodes){
    huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount + i].count = huffmanTreeNode[mergedHuffmanNodes].count + huffmanTreeNode[mergedHuffmanNodes + 1].count;
    huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount + i].left = &huffmanTreeNode[mergedHuffmanNodes];
    huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount + i].right = &huffmanTreeNode[mergedHuffmanNodes + 1];
    head_huffmanTreeNode = &(huffmanTreeNode[distinctCharacterCount + i]);
}

// get bitSequence sequence for each char value
void buildHuffmanDictionary(struct huffmanTree *root, unsigned char *bitSequence, unsigned char bitSequenceLength){
    if (root->left){
        bitSequence[bitSequenceLength] = 0;
        buildHuffmanDictionary(root->left, bitSequence, bitSequenceLength + 1);
    }

    if (root->right){
        bitSequence[bitSequenceLength] = 1;
        buildHuffmanDictionary(root->right, bitSequence, bitSequenceLength + 1);
    }

    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
        huffmanDictionary[root->letter].bitSequenceLength = bitSequenceLength;
        memcpy(huffmanDictionary[root->letter].bitSequence, bitSequence, bitSequenceLength * sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
}
```

And file (serialHeader.h):

```
{
    unsigned char bitSequence[255];
    unsigned char bitSequenceLength;
};

struct huffmanTree
{
    unsigned char letter;
    unsigned int count;
    struct huffmanTree *left, *right;
};

extern struct huffmanDictionary huffmanDictionary[256];
extern struct huffmanTree *head_huffmanTreeNode;
extern struct huffmanTree huffmanTreeNode[512];

void sortHuffmanTree(int i, int distinctCharacterCount, int combinedHuffmanNodes);
void buildHuffmanTree(int i, int distinctCharacterCount, int combinedHuffmanNodes);
void buildHuffmanDictionary(struct huffmanTree *root, unsigned char *bitSequence, unsigned char bitSequenceLength);
int wrapperGPU(char **file, unsigned char *inputFileData, int inputFileLength);
```

I run the program with an input text file and an output file (empty or non-existent)

`mpirun -np 2 ./MPI_compress input output`

I get the following message at the end of the run:

```
free(): invalid size

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 8804 RUNNING AT Inspiron
=   EXIT CODE: 134
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Aborted (signal 6)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

What is causing this error in the code?

Comment: The error messages says `free(): invalid size`. You're probably trying to free a resource that was not allocated, most likely `head_huffmanTreeNode`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a mistake in

```
for (b = mergedHuffmanNodes; b < distinctCharacterCount - 1 + i; b++){
```

in `sortHuffmanTree()`

because on the next line you do

```
if (huffmanTreeNode[b].count > huffmanTreeNode[b + 1].count){
```

where `b + 1` may be out of bounds.